# How to print a visual representation of a palindrome with a recursive function?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I wanted to write a recursive function which takes a palindrome as a string and then prints a specific visual representation of it (see picture). Can anyone tell me how I can include the spaces at the beginning of each printed line so that the whole printout is "mirrored"? Mine is totally distorted. 
Many thanks in advance for helping me out!

This is how my print looks like

[image: This is how my print looks like]

And this is what I want it to look like

[image: And this is what I want it to look like]

This is my code from the printout:

```
def print_palindrome(p):
    if len(p) <= 1:
        print(p)
    else:
        print(len(p)*" " + p[0] + len(p)*" " + p[-1])
        return print_palindrome(p[1:-1])

print_palindrome("murder for a jar of red rum")
```

Comment: the problem is that p gets shorter in the recussive calls so you print the wrong number of spaces at the start of the line. maybe change the first `len(p)*" "` to `(40-len(p)/2)*" "`  40 is just a made up constant, use half the page width, or half the length of the original string.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I just tried it and if gives me the following error message: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'... any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a counter in the recursive function to indicate which line you are in. Otherwise how would the function know how many spaces to print at the start?

Here is my modification to your code:

```
def print_palindrome(p):
    print_palindrome_rec(p, 0)

def print_palindrome_rec(p, i):
    if len(p) <= 1:
        print(i*" " + p)
    else:
        print(i*" " + p[0] + (len(p)-2)*" " + p[-1])
        print_palindrome_rec(p[1:-1], i+1)

print_palindrome("murder for a jar of red rum")
```